# Indexing out of bounds in row reversal of matrix

Tags: java, matrix

```
public static int [][] reverseRows (int [][] matrix ) {
    int i, j, k = (matrix.length - 1), l = (matrix[0].length - 1);
    int [][] rr = new int[matrix.length][matrix[0].length];

    for(i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++)
            rr[k][l--] = matrix[i][j]; // <--- This line
        k--;
    }
    printMatrix(rr);
    return matrix;
}
```

I'm trying to reverse the rows in a matrix passed as a parameter, and I've come up with this contraption. It works for a 1x1 matrix, for obvious reasons, but not for others, and I am getting this error:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

on the line that is indicated by the comment. So my `l` iterator is clearly being indexed too far back, past 0 (to -1, if my eyes don't deceive me). Wouldn't `l` iterate the same amount of times as `j`? Since they are the same size, why wouldn't `j` be reading past the end of `matrix` but `l` is reading past `rr`?

Comment: thank you for making those edits :)

Comment: Sure thing, good luck getting assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code will work fine for one iteration

```
for(i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++)
            rr[k][l--] = matrix[i][j]; // <--- This line
        k--;
    }
```

You have to assign l again `l = matrix[0].length-1` for next iteration

```
for(i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        l = matrix[0].length - 1; // <--- This line
        for(j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++)
            rr[k][l--] = matrix[i][j]; 
        k--;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Right. Because it would be 0 at the start of the next loop. Thank you for the assistance :)

Comment: Glad that it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to re-assign the value of 'l' after each j loop, in the way that your code is, variable 'l' is being decremented i*j times.
Try something like:

```
public static int [][] reverseRows (int [][] matrix ) {
    int i, j, k = (matrix.length - 1), l = (matrix[0].length - 1);
    int [][] rr = new int[matrix.length][matrix[0].length];

    for(i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        l = (matrix[0].length - 1);
        for(j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++)
            rr[k][l--] = matrix[i][j]; // <--- This line
        k--;
    }
    printMatrix(rr);
    return matrix;
}
```